apt-get dist-upgrade wants to remove qt6-wayland and wireshark
Issue with proposed dist-upgrade
A dry-run of apt-get dist-upgrade shows that qt6-wayland and wireshark would be removed upon execution. I am wondering:

Why will these packages be removed? Is it an issue with the packages or is it a result of an earlier problem that I had faced? (see context below)
What is the recommended way to mitigate this? (e.g., mark the packages)
Why wireshark would be removed but wireshark-common would be upgraded?

Below the current versions of the said packages:
~$ dpkg -l qt6-wayland wireshark
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version      Architecture Description
+++-=================-============-============-==============================================
ii  qt6-wayland:amd64 6.4.2-5+b2   amd64        Qt 6 Wayland platform plugin
ii  wireshark         4.2.5-1      amd64        network traffic analyzer - graphical interface

Following: complete dry-run output.
~$ apt-get dist-upgrade -s
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libb2-1 libbcg729-0 libcares2 libnghttp3-3 libnghttp3-9 libqt6core5compat6 libqt6core6t64 libroc0.3 libsmi2t64 libts0t64 libwireshark-data
  libwireshark17t64 libwiretap14t64 libwsutil15t64 qt6-translations-l10n wireshark-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libqt6dbus6t64 libqt6gui6t64 libqt6multimedia6 libqt6network6t64 libqt6opengl6t64 libqt6printsupport6t64 libqt6qml6 libqt6qmlmodels6 libqt6quick6
  libqt6svg6 libqt6waylandclient6 libqt6waylandcompositor6 libqt6waylandeglclienthwintegration6 libqt6waylandeglcompositorhwintegration6
  libqt6widgets6t64 libqt6wlshellintegration6 qt6-gtk-platformtheme qt6-qpa-plugins qt6-wayland wireshark
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-inter-variable heif-gdk-pixbuf heif-thumbnailer libavif-gdk-pixbuf libjxl-gdk-pixbuf libmpfi0 libnghttp3-9 libpython3.12-minimal
  libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12t64 libroc0.4 libsvtav1enc2 linux-image-6.9.8-amd64 linux-sysctl-defaults python3.12 python3.12-minimal
  python3.12-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  evince firmware-linux-free gir1.2-rb-3.0 gnome gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-session gnome-session-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libavif16 libevdocument3-4t64 libevview3-3t64 libges-1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libkpathsea6 libnss-systemd
  libpam-systemd libpeas-1.0-0 libpipewire-0.3-0t64 libpipewire-0.3-modules libptexenc1 libpython3-stdlib libqt6core5compat6 libqt6core6t64
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core10 libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-modules libsynctex2 libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386
  libtexlua53-5 libwireplumber-0.5-0 libwireshark17t64 linux-image-amd64 pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse procps python3
  python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-dbus python3-gi python3-gi-cairo
  python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-numpy python3-pikepdf python3-uno python3-venv python3-wrapt rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins shotwell shotwell-common systemd systemd-cryptsetup systemd-timesyncd texlive-base
  texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german
  texlive-lang-greek texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-luatex texlive-pictures texlive-plain-generic
  texlive-science texlive-xetex vim vim-common vim-nox vim-runtime vim-tiny wireplumber wireshark-common
101 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 20 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Context
I am using Debian testing (trixie). A few months ago, I was caught in the time_t transition, resulting in having multiple packages removed after an apt-get dist-upgrade execution.
I had fixed the issue by manually re-installing the key packages:
apt-get install gdm3 nautilus software-properties-gtk task-gnome-desktop p7zip-full

Since then, I have been exclusively updating my system using apt-get upgrade, allowing the migration to complete gracefully.
Please note that I have already upgraded the existing packages (apt-get upgrade) before this dry-run.
